# Custom scrollbars for DATATABLES

Tags: datatables, scrollbar

Is there any way to customize the scrollbars for the DataTables..?

Comment: How would you like to customize it?  Do you have an example scrollbar code that you can show us that you'd like to customize it to?

Answer (score 3):

You can use jScrollPane for this:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

We are currently using the older version but it can be wired up to the datatable after the datatable has been initialised.  there will be a a fair bit of CSS work here as well but this is the crux of the code you need to get started:

```
$('#foo').dataTable({
    "fnInitComplete": function() {
        // custom scroll bars
        $('#icis_dashboard')
        .find('.dataTables_scrollBody')
        .jScrollPane();
    },
    "sScrollY": "242px"
});
```